# Unlock this question since its title has been improved?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

[Unable to find the .lit file reader app clit](https://askubuntu.com/q/740492/239648)

I know that the question has good answers, and there is no practical reason to unlock it. However, in theoretical, I don't think it should be locked anymore. After this question has a better name and a reminder of the mod, and since it has stopped appearing in the Hot Questions board, the off-topic comments about the word won't appear anymore, IMO. Starting from now, I think only people who actually care about the library would only visit the question. Those who when googling will definitely search `clit` together with other keyword, such as `ubuntu` or `linux`. I have tested my guess with `clit ubuntu` and `clit linux` in a private tab, and at least all the results in the front page are purely on-topic.

IMO, there is no harm to keep it locked, but only benefit to unlock it. So I vote to unlock it.

PS: I can't find the tag "lock".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That  was a pretty funny question title, but I don't think that is the only reason he locked it, based on James comment, the comment section was full of comments about the word `clit` and as that is still in the question, it will likely stay closed to avoid further discussion.

You can't search for that question without getting porn as the result and I understand English is not everyones first language, so these things happen but this seems like it would just descend back in to a discussion about the word and that is off topic.

As the question has two (one accepted) high voted answers, I see no reason to  reopen this and allow the conversation to start back up.

I vote leave it locked to keep it within the scope of the site, if you disagree, please do say why, but the title alone being edited would not stop people from making jokes about the rest of it in the comments.

Comment: I have elaborated why I propose to unlock it in my question. Thanks for stopping by

Comment: "Starting from now, I think only people who actually care about the library would only visit the question" Why? This question is all over the Internet, it is on many sites like twitter and is still getting views. The issue is with the users who just come from these sites for a laugh and leave silly comments.

Comment: "IMO, there is no harm to keep it locked, but only benefit to unlock it" This may be true but you fail to mention any reason to open it again. Mods won't deal in hypothetical reasons, you need facts.

Comment: My point is even when the question is available else where on the internet, it will eventually sink down. I don't know when it happens, but it will. And when it does, only serious users seeking for help visit the question. About the fact, I don't have any number to back up my point. However, if the true evidence is the activity of it after it gets unlocked, then it only comes in the future. How can you ask for the thing in the future, when you don't let it happens first?

Comment: I did not ask for `evidence` only reasons, if you can't give reasons then I can't help you get it reopened. Sure the controversy will go away eventually but it has only been two days all it takes is one user to start it up again. "How can you ask for the thing in the future, when you don't let it happens first?" It is not up to me to vote it back open and see what happens, it is your request and you MUST have a good reason.

Comment: *all it takes is one user to start it up again* - Excellent. This makes me accepts your answer.

Comment: Hi! This basically sums up why I locked it. There were a large number of comments, and it was attracting attention from other sites on the network as well. I wish everyone was an adult, but sadly many people were immature about it. :-(